# How do I figure out which regular expression matches my string?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have 10 regular expressions and 1 one string which may or may not match exactly one of those 10 regular expressions. Does anyone know of a simple way to figure out which regular expression, if any, matches my string? I know that I can simply test each one against the string but I'd like to know if there's a library out there that I can input the regular expressions and the string and it'll tell me if any of my regular expressions match. I need to know which regular expression is matched because the resulting business logic is different for each regular expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the API you're looking for. Just invoke it for each of the 10 expressions!

```
public boolean testMatch(String data, String regEx) {
    return data.matches(regEx);
}
```

Let's make it more generic.

```
public String testMatch(String data, String... regExs) {
    for(String regEx : regExs) {
        if(data.matches(regEx)) {
            return regEx;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: The downside of this approach is that every time that you call the `testMatch` method, all the Patterns will need to be recompiled again.

Comment: Yes, of course we can have the patterns compiled beforehand like that way you've shown. But the list of regular expressions is dynamic here. You wouldn't save much by doing `Pattern.compile`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
String charsequence = "Whatever";
List<Pattern> patterns = null/* Place here all your RegExp*/;

Matcher matcher = null;
for (Pattern p: patterns) {
    matcher = p.matcher(charsequence);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        // It matches, do stuff
        break;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Regards

Comment: I'm not sure if we can have all the regular expressions compiled beforehand as they could come on-the-fly from an external source, leaving little benefits with precompiling.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that you are going to have different logic based on which expression matches. I don't think you can avoid looping through each option (or having another class loop through each option).

You could create classes that have the regular expression and the action to preform and pass the String to that class and let it preform the action if it matches rather than determine a match and have some switch like structure determine the action to preform.

Comment: Alternations or `|`s are expensive

Comment: @Adarshr, the question was not asking for the least expensive option.  Besides is it really more expensive than 10 individual matches?

Comment: You're right. Because this is a reverse of pattern matching, it doesn't matter much. But on a general note, it certainly matters, doesn't it?